# Algolia not removing the record

Tags: algolia

I got 200 from the request in the logs and the response is

```
{
  "deletedAt": "2015-09-03T10:29:12.280Z",
  "taskID": 346901460,
  "objectID": "11060"
}
```

but I checked the dashboard and the record is still there.

I use this package

> https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel

Answer (score 2):

The problem was I was not setting the

```
ObjectId
```

correctly.